Arrival date to Buenos Aires from Spain of Segundo Cela Montero between 1895 and 1918
I am searching to find the arrival of my grandfather Segundo Cela Montero to Buenos Aires Argentina. He was born in Herreros de Jamuz Leon Spain on March 29, 1881, and he migrated to Argentina between 1895 and 1918. He was the father of my father Salvador Francisco Cela who was born in Buenos Aires on July 31 1911 in Huinca Renanco Cordoba Argentina. My grandfather Segundo Cela left Spain on a ship bound to Buenos Aires from the port of Vigo or from La Coruña Spain.
